# Areas in applied math related to differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, applications

I am currently a third year student in university. So far, most courses I have taken are centered at pure math, with a special focus on differential geometry. However I do start to feel that the pursuit of pure math is a lot harder than I had imagined. So, I am considering changing my focus to something in applied math, without having to starting all over. Also, I should probably start to do some research by now. Is there any field in applied math, where I can make use of all the differential geometry I have learned, so that I don't have to start from scratch?

I'd also like to know whether there is a tight connection between differential geometry and optimal transport theory, or between differential geometry and computational geometry.

Comment: This has been often asked. For some interesting informations see for example [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/213014/how-is-differential-geometry-used-in-immediate-industrial-applications-and-what), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88938/immediate-applications-of-differential-geometry), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584551/applications-of-differential-geometry-in-artificial-intelligence/2929482#2929482) etc. You can search for applications of differential geometry to other applied areas yourself.

Comment: Optimization on Riemannian manifolds is an active area of research. But I would say, if you are going to switch to applied math, don't restrict yourself to doing something related to differential geometry, because that is a severe restriction. Just start fresh and go in a direction that is most promising, like computational genomics or something like that. The mathematical maturity you gained by studying differential geometry will help you learn applied math easily.